# Local Policy Group

Tags: domain

I try to log on to the computer server as a user, this error prompt to me.

Local policy does not permit you to log on interactively.

How can i enable the server computer to log in even the Domain USers.

Comment: Computers don't log in, users do.

Answer (score -1):

Why on earth would you want a user to logon to a server? Not even an administrator should do that unless he really has to. All logon should be done through clients.

Anyway, if you are dead set on this, you can create or edit a domain policy to allow user groups to log on locally.

Comment: Specifically, use the "Allow log on locally" setting.

Comment: I know that a user MUST not have an access to the Server. I wanna try if the Global Security Group is working.  because I set permission in a particualr folder for a selected Group only, but still all user and group can access the folder i want to have restrictions.

Comment: Have you checked that there aren't some other right still active that overwrites you settings? Like Everyone? Really, you should create a topic of your issue, then you would be more likely to get the help you need.